# When building a Maven project in Docker, all target files are rooted

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have a Maven project which I want to build in a Docker container, so that I don't have to install Java, Maven, ... on my Jenkins system.

I build the Maven project as following:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
                    -v $(pwd):/opt/maven
                    -w /opt/maven
                    maven
                    mvn clean install
```

This works great, the build is correctly made. However, when doing this as my regular user, all files in the `target/` directory are owned by `root` and no by `jester`, which is my current user.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: The docker daemon runs as root.  This means when it writes files in the file system they are owned by root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chan check out the option -u, as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/nitrobin/4d16fbe347c150a422ad), which wraps docker run in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
test ":$DEBUG" != :true || set -x

# set image
set -- debian:jessie "$@"

# use current user and its groups at host
for v in /etc/group /etc/passwd; do
  [ ! -r "$v" ] || set -- -v $v:$v:ro "$@"
done
set -- --user "`id -u`:`id -g`" "$@"
for g in `id -G`; do
  set -- --group-add "$g" "$@"
done
set -- -v "$HOME":"$HOME" "$@"

exec docker run --rm -it "$@"
```

The goal is to make sure the container mounts the local user definition, and uses the same uid/gid.